# What is $T^*(\mathbb{A}^1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\mathbb{A}^1$ be the affine line and $T^*(\mathbb{A}^1)$ the contangent space of $\mathbb{A}^1$. What is $T^*(\mathbb{A}^1)$? Is $T^*(\mathbb{A}^1) = \mathbb{A}^2$? Thank you very much.

Comment: $T^\ast \mathbf A^1$ is the cotangent _bundle_. To answer your question: yes, it is isomorphic to $\mathbf A^2$: if $x$ is the coordinate on $\mathbf A^1$, then $dx$ is a nowhere-zero global section of $T^\ast \mathbf A^1$.

Comment: Just to add what Asal said, you know that $\Omega_{\mathbb{A}^1/k}=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}$. So, $T_{\mathbb{A}^1/k}=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}^\vee=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}$. So, the associated bundle is $\mathcal{Sym}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}[t])=\mathbb{A}^2$.